# Sharing text highlights with javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, text, position, highlight

I have to write a webapp with jQuery Mobile for reading a HTML document, and highlighting and sharing text fragments between two or more users that are reading the same document. For example, I and Bob are using this webapp for reading the same web page; I'd want that Bob can view my highlights and I can view Bob's ones.

The problem is: how can I get the absolute position of the highlights in my instance of the webapp, so I can send it to Bob's instance? Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: read up on webRTC (it's bleeding edge tech and only currently working in Chrome). Alternatively run a Node.JS + Socket.io solution to communicate between the two.

Comment: The problem is not the communication, but to find a way to get the position of the highligheted test of user A, so I can reapply the highlight to user B.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range), which you can get with `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)`

As the link describes, that object has properties which describe the beginning and end of the selection in terms of the elements which the selection starts and ends in, and a numeric offset from the first textual "space" in those elements.

To pass that over the wire, you'll need a consistent identifier for the start and end elements.  If every element in the document has an ID which is the same no matter who's viewing it, then you could use that.  Otherwise, you'll need to determine some custom serialization to uniquely identify elements within your markup.